# Cyberduck Replacement?

Tags: mac, ftp, file-transfer, sftp

Now that I've upgraded my Mac OS X to Snow Leopard, Cyberduck does not work.

What are some good replacements?
I would like to have both ftp and sftp compatibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to download the [beta of Cyberduck](http://update.cyberduck.ch/beta/Cyberduck-3.3b1.zip) to make it work correctly under Snow Leopard.

When reading this, it's probably not such a bad idea to go to the [website](http://cyberduck.ch/), and grab the latest version.

Comment: There's a more recent version 3.3b2 available now: http://update.cyberduck.ch/beta/Cyberduck-3.3b2.zip It is not (yet) listed on http://cyberduck.ch/changelog/

Answer (score 8):

Just upgrade Cyberduck to [version 3.3b1](http://cyberduck.ch/changelog/) or later!

Comment: thanks!
accepted eveilchookie because he answered a minute faster :(

Comment: I'm not here for any reputation, so your choice is perfectly fine, if only as it links to the 3.3b1 version directly. But still I answered at 22:21.49, while the other answer was at 22:22.35 :-) (For anyone reading this question some time later: please follow my link to get the latest version, which might not be 3.3b1 at the time you read this.)

Comment: If you WERE here for reputation, you did okay. At the present moment, the other guy has 5 upvotes and one accepted answer. You have 6 + 1 comment upvote. Not bad. I mean, not that we care about rep :) But since you do not, I will upvote you.